# Is there a better approach to html standards validation than w3c validator?

Tags: html, w3c-validation, semantic-markup

Granted, this is a very generic question, but I am wondering if w3c validation is considered a best practice for html validation, or if there are better approaches to ensure contemporary standards-compliant markup.

This question arose when I noticed duplicate IDs on [an MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text) (a site I would have assumed would be very strict about its coding practices). It appeared to be an artifact of how they generated the sections of the page.

Curious, I validated the page's code on the w3c validator, and there were various "errors" that suggested that MDN was just ignoring that a certain attribute or value was not valid. Generally, these related to seemingly appropriate uses of `rel` attributes.

I was left wondering if standards for valid, semantic markup matter less, or if there's a new ideal approach to code validation and standardization than relying on w3c validation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maintainer of the current [W3C HTML Checker](https://validator.w3.org/nu/) (validator) here. I think it's important to understand the intended purpose of the current HTML checker, which is different from the purpose of the legacy W3C Markup Validator.

The purpose of the checker is documented at https://validator.w3.org/nu/about.html#why-validate:

> The core reason to run your HTML documents through a conformance checker is simple: To catch unintended mistakes—mistakes you might have otherwise missed—so that you can fix them.
>
> Beyond that, some document-conformance requirements (validity rules) in the HTML spec are there to help you and the users of your documents avoid certain kinds of potential problems.
>
> There are some markup cases defined as errors because they are potential problems for accessibility, usability, interoperability, security, or maintainability—or because they can result in poor performance, or that might cause your scripts to fail in ways that are hard to troubleshoot.
>   Along with those, some markup cases are defined as errors because they can cause you to run into potential problems in HTML parsing and error-handling behavior—so that, say, you’d end up with some unintuitive, unexpected result in the DOM
>
> Validating your documents alerts you to those potential problems.

So as far as your question about "are better approaches to ensure contemporary standards-compliant markup", the answer is that it's not an either-or thing; there are a variety of approaches and the W3C HTML Checker is just one of them, and its goal isn't to be the single way to determine anything but instead to just help you catch mistakes you might otherwise miss and that might cause unexpected problems for your users.

---

As far as ways to get alerted to specific device issues or browser-implementation issues, we don’t have good automated checking tools for that, but a couple of things which are huge help there are:

- https://caniuse.com/ — detailed information about the level of support for particular web-runtime features in different browsers, and in different versions of those browsers, and in release of the browsers for  mobile devices vs desktop
- https://wptdashboard.appspot.com/ — current test results across all major browser engines for dozens of web-runtime features/specs; if https://caniuse.com/ doesn’t have information about a particular feature, you can look through this dashboard and browse to the directory that has tests for that feature, and find whether a browser passes the tests for the feature

But as far as good automated tools we do actually have for checking other things, here are two:

- https://validator.w3.org/i18n-checker/ — W3C Internationalization Checker
- https://observatory.mozilla.org/ — for doing a security assessment of the content of your site

Comment: This is very helpful. Thank you.My only follow up question is are there checking tools that you think are helpful for alerting a developer to specific device or browser standards implementation issues? I understand it's a very fluid context, but I am mainly just curious and haven't found anything I like yet.

Comment: One tool not really in the class you describe that I think is very useful is the W3C Internationalization Checker https://validator.w3.org/i18n-checker/ Another that’s probably even further than what you describe but I think is also really useful is https://observatory.mozilla.org/ (security-related site checking). But as far as alerting developers to specific device issues or browser-implementation issues, there aren’t good automated tools for that. What is good for that though is https://caniuse.com/. And another good thing is https://wptdashboard.appspot.com/. I’ll add those to the answer

Comment: Thank you for these resources. I am very familiar with caniuse.com, bit I was not familiar with wptdashboard, observatory or the internationalization checker.

I suppose the best thing to do would be to put together a compliance,configuration, and testing suite that I run through as part of my internal QA process.

Have a good one and thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced a problem with mentioned above [W3C HTML Checker](https://validator.w3.org/nu/). I respect a huge amount of work that was done by author of this validator, but it did not allow me **in any way** a tag `<script type="text/vbscript" src="file.vbs">`. It was said to change `type` value to *empty string, a JavaScript MIME type, or module*, which makes my page useless.

I know than VBScript language is rarely used now, it was just a test page, but let me share with you less tricky alternative, as good as the first one for HTML error checking.

Maintainer of the current **JsonFormatter** (validator) is [here](https://jsonformatter.org/html-validator)